# How to skip outputting data that does not meet all requirements in BeautifulSoup and Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am fairly new to Python and BeautifulSoup. I am trying to make a script that asks what job/career you'd like and what location you want to work in. Then scrapes indeed and outputs the data to an excel file. It all works fine except the fact that some of the job listing do not have the salary listed on Indeed itself, therefore I think, BeautifulSoup will still scrape the title and location, but obviously not the salary, then what ive found happens is - all of the data is mixed up when it is outputted, as in there will be the wrong salary next to the job, due to BeautifulSoup still parsing all titles and locations, but not all salaries, so the data is mixed up, at least in terms of salary.

Now I have two options - I could try to make the script output all data except salary for the job listings thyt do not have it, so the excel spreadsheet shows 'salary' as blank, but I do not know how to do this.

Or I could completely skip parsing ALL data for those that do not have 'salary' listed. And only parse the ones that have all 3 of the requirements satisfied, title, location, salary. But again, I do not know how to do this.

Here is my code, I'm aware its very messy -  I'm new to Python.

```py
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import pandas

 new_jobs = []
 data = []
 new_wage = []
 new_location = []

 indeed_search = input("What jobs are you interested in?")
 for chars in indeed_search:
     chars.replace(" ","+")

 location = input("Where do you wanna work?")
 for loc in location:
     loc.replace(" ","+")

 file_name = input("What's your file going to be called?") + ".xlsx"

 for i in range(1,10):
     page = requests.get("https://www.indeed.co.uk/jobs?q=" + indeed_search + "&l=" + "&start={}".format(i))
     soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
     for wage in soup.find_all(class_="salaryText"):
         new_wage.append(wage.text.strip())

     for jobs in soup.find_all(class_="title"):
         new_jobs.append(jobs.text.strip())

     for location in soup.find_all(class_="location accessible-contrast-color-location"):
         new_location.append(location.text.strip())

     data_new = list(zip(new_jobs, new_location, new_wage))
     d = pandas.DataFrame(data_new, columns=["Job", "Location", "Salary"])
     d.to_excel("C://Users//steve//Downloads//" + file_name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think you need to find the job card, then iter through all cards, in each card you can find each title, salary, and location, also at the same time check if they are existed, otherwise replace them with np.NaN, or something else.

So I have reshaped your code a little bit as below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = []

indeed_search = input("What jobs are you interested in?")
for chars in indeed_search:
     chars.replace(" ","+")

location = input("Where do you wanna work?")
for loc in location:
     loc.replace(" ","+")

file_name = input("What's your file going to be called?") + ".xlsx"

for i in range(0, 20, 10):
    url = "https://www.indeed.co.uk/jobs?q=" + indeed_search + "&l=" + location + "&start={}".format(i)
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    for job in soup.find_all(class_='jobsearch-SerpJobCard'):
        title = job.find(class_="title")
        salary = job.find(class_="salaryText")
        loc = job.find(class_="location")

        title = title.get_text().strip() if title else np.NaN
        salary = salary.get_text().strip() if salary else np.NaN
        loc = loc.get_text().strip() if loc else np.NaN
        data.append((title,salary,loc))


d = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['title','salary','location'])
d.to_excel("C://Users//steve//Downloads//" + file_name)
```